# display: inline does not work with jquery animate ()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a div that is hidden by default on mousing over the header of a site here is the jquery code that does not currently work:

```
    $("#header_title").mouseenter(function() {
        $('#header_links').animate({
            display: "inline",
            width: "600px"
            }, 1500 );
    });

    $("#header").mouseleave(function() {
        $('#header_links').css({
            display: "none",
            }, 1500 );
    });
```

It works fine when I change animate to css, however I dont want the menu to just appear, I want it to animate after being hidden. Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231937/animating-inline-elements-with-jquery

Comment: `inline-block` not going to work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to animate it back to zero width, and you can't animate the display property, that's either visible or not, there's nothing to animate inbetween, as it's not a numerical property ?

```
$("#header_title").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#header_links').css('display','inline').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: 600
    }, 1500 );
});

$("#header").mouseleave(function() {
    $('#header_links').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        width: 0
    }, 1500, function() {
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with this solution, the links are still clickable... that is why i need to use the display property and change it to none somehow before and after animating...

Comment: @pwneth - you could always just set the display property, but you still can't animate it, edited the answer.